# Как использовать интернет сразу нескольких провайдеров?

Tags: провайдер

Здраствуйте, есть интернет по модему и по сети, я могу использовать только один. Как мне, для увеличения скорости скачивания использовать обоих провайдеров?

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, если Вам помог ответ - жмакните по галке слева под кулчаком вниз. ![alt text][1](взято из ответа @shaman888)  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/lPQEm.png

Answer (score 1):

Скорость закачки увеличить не получится, но вы можете сбалансировать трафик между двух интерфейсов. Балансировать можно по разному, по типу трафика, по запросам, по загруженности интерфейса. Т.е. загрузку одного файла, с помощью двух провайдеров, сделать не получится. А два файла, по разным провайдерам, можно, с помощью выше указанных способов.

Answer (score 0):

Указать два шлюза и распределение нагрузки.

Answer (score 0):

Ставишь 2 сетевые карты на комп, настраиваешь маршрутизацию и вперед. Но совместно использовать "два" интернета не получится (если вы хотите увеличить скорость или что то в этом роде. Данную штуку рекомендуем ставить у абонентов, чья работа зависит от интернета (биржевики). Если один полетел - сразу подрубается второй.